# Get the underlying type of a boost::variant

Tags: c++, serialization, boost-variant

We can use `get<i>(var)` to get the `ith` type of a boost::variant, where `i` normally is a compile-time known constant. However, in some situation, `i` is only known during the runtime. For example:

```
void do_process(int i, boost::variant<int, double, string>& var) {
  // How can I get the underlying type of var based on i?
}
```

The purpose here is I am implementing a serialization/deserialization interface, while for serialization I can actually use `visitor` because the object to be serialized in known. For `deserialization`, it looks like the only way I can do is to extract the data from the type index (`var.which()`) and the store data to the underlying type.

Comment: How about this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313108/construct-a-boost-variant-containing-a-value-of-the-nth-type-in-the-variant-type